# jquery on click with not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data which is loaded via ajax and I would like to disable a click event on li element which has a class `active`, the below is what I tried. can someone help me out?

```
$('body').on("click", 'li *:not(.active)', function (e) {
    //do something
}); //this doesn't work
```

Comment: `.click()` function is more appropriate.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde - `.click()` won't work with dynamically added content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting all non-active **descendants** of list items.

- Remove the universal selector
- Remove the descendant combinator

Such:

```
'li:not(.active)'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `active` class is on the `li` then remove the space and `*` (*which targets all descendant elements that do not have the `active` class*)

```
$('body').on("click", 'li:not(.active)', function (e) {
    //do something
}); //this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, that code is not looking at an li element, thatmselector is looking for a child of an li element. Get rid of the space and * and it will check the li.

```
li:not(.active)
```